# Get variable of nested async function in javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, mongoose, socket.io

I have a problem with a nested callback-function, where I need a variable of.

So I have a socketio connection and the client emits a 'getsettings' to get some data via a callback

client:

```
Socket.emit('getSettings', function (err, res) {
    console.log('Settings retrieved');
    console.log(res);
    $scope.ip = res.ip;
    $scope.port = res.port;
});
```

The answer of the nodejs server looks as follows, commented is the code which won't work like I hoped.

nodejs-server:

```
socket.on('getSettings', function (placeholder, callback) {

    console.log('Settings are broadcasted.');
    // this following "data" variable shall be omitted once the find() problem is solved 
    var data = {
        ip: '192.168.188.32',
        port: '9000'
    };

    // Here I try to get the data from mongodb-database collection "lmssettings"
    // via the mongoose-function find().
    // This won't work because of its async behavior
    //
    // lmsSettings.find({}, function (err, res) {
    //    data = res;
    // });

    callback(false, data); 
});
```

I'm new to JS and read a lot about it so that I know that it is a problem with the async behavior of the find-function of mongoose, but I don't know how to change the code, that it will work properly.

Hope anyone has a hint for me. Thx in advance...

Comment: Is the `data` variable that's not commented out just placeholder data?

Comment: Place the `callback(false, data); ` inside the callback for `lmsSetting`

Comment: @adeneo Put your comment in as an answer (which it is) so the OP can accept :)

Comment: I have answer to you problem (already posted), but just one question: why do you set the data, and then later re-set it, without using it. What's the point?

Comment: @SimpleJ you mean the data in function(data,callback). I think so, tried to omit it, but then the socketio connection crashed. I will edit it so it won't confuse one

Comment: @maremp Hi, the first set of data is just to check if everything works properly... in the end, the part with var data = { ip ...} shall be omitted and replaced by the data I got from the fing() function

Comment: Oh okay, just checking so you don't do things like this, since it's redundant. You could just use `res` for callback, since you set it to data. Both works, but it's cleaner and clean code is better code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Async function have a callback, use the received data (`res`) from `.find` callback and pass it to your `callback` function:

```
socket.on('getSettings', function (data, callback) {

    console.log('Settings are broadcasted.');

    lmsSettings.find({}, function (err, res) {
        callback(false, res); 
    });
});
```

I think this should fix your problem.

Comment: Damm, thats it. I already had it like this. The reason why it didn't work, was that grunt wasn't running on my test-machine. Thx for everything

Comment: I already tried, but I'm to new to vote. :/ Hope sb else can vote it up. Perhaps you can omit the "var data = { ip ...}" - part of the solution. Think its more confusing then helpful, because the data will be overridden in the find()-function anyway...

Comment: Fixed it. Oh I forgot about that. But I'm almost sure that you can accept the answer, it's the [checkmark beneath the upvote counter](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235).